# Use private ips in google dataflow job being created via google provided template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to set up a dataflow job via deployment manager using the google provided template `Cloud_PubSub_to_Avro`. 
To do this I had to register dataflow as a type provider, like this:

```
resources:
- name: 'register-dataflow'
  action: 'gcp-types/deploymentmanager-v2beta:deploymentmanager.typeProviders.insert'
  properties:
    name: 'dataflow'
    descriptorUrl: 'https://dataflow.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1b3'
    options:
      inputMappings:
        - fieldName: Authorization
          location: HEADER
          value: >
        $.concat("Bearer ", $.googleOauth2AccessToken())
```

Then I created my job template that looks something like

```
resources:
- name: "my-topic-to-avro"
  type: 'my-project-id/dataflow:dataflow.projects.locations.templates.launch'
  properties:
    projectId: my-project-id
    gcsPath: "gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Cloud_PubSub_to_Avro"
    jobName: "my-topic-to-avro"
    location: "europe-west1"
    parameters:
      inputTopic: "projects/my-project-id/topics/my-topic"
      outputDirectory: "gs://my-bucket/avro/my-topic/"
      avroTempDirectory: "gs://my-bucket/avro/tmp/my-topic/"
```

Now I'm trying to understand how I can tell my job to not use public ips. From [this](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks#public_ip_parameter) it looks like I need to set `--usePublicIps=false` but I can't figure out where to place this parameter, or if this is even possible. 
A possible workaround I found [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/delete-access-config) would be to remove the access-config, but again I haven't been able to figure out how to do this, if at all possible.

Is what I'm trying to do possible through provided templates or will I have to use the dataflow API? 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with templates, but here goes:
I see that you should be able to pass "network" and "subnetwork" under "environment": https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks#using_the_rest_api, but I don't see an option for usePublicIPs (perhaps passing it under "parameters" might work?)

Comment: at the moment we're using default network and subnetwork, I passed them in explicitly but that didn't seem to address the issue. I tried passiin `usePublicIps` in parameters but deployment manager doesn't recognize it as know field name.

Comment: It seems that the template API doesn't support that setting. I've opened an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/129085515

Comment: Also, a possible (untested) workaround could be to: download a copy of the template (gsutil cp gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Cloud_PubSub_to_Avro .), add `"usePublicIps", false,` under "options", upload it back to a bucket of your choosing, and update gcsPath in your template.